# fsolve gives weird answers

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to use `fsolve` to numerically find roots of a nonlinear transcendent equation.

The following code does this job.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kappa = 0.1
tau = 90

def equation(x, * parameters):
    kappa,tau = parameters
    return -x + kappa * np.sin(-tau*x)

x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5, 35)
roots = fsolve(equation,x, (kappa,tau))

x_2 = np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,1500)
plt.plot(x_2 ,x_2 )
plt.plot(x_2 , kappa*np.sin(-x_2 *tau))
plt.scatter(x, roots)
plt.show()
```

I can double-check the solutions graphically by plotting the two graphs `f1(x) = x` and `f2(x) = k*sin(-x*tau)`, which I also included in the code. `fsolve` gives me some wrong answers, without throwing any errors or convergence problems.

The problem is, that I would like to automate the procedure for varying `kappa` and `tau`, without me checking which answers are wrong and which are right. But with wrong answers as output, I can't use this method. Is there any other method or an option I can use, to be on the safe side?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't run your code, there were errors and anyway, according to the documentation on [scipy.fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), you're supposed to add an initial guess as the second input argument, not a range as what you did there `fsolve(equation, x0, (kappa,tau))`

You could of course however pass this in a loop, looping for every value in the array `np.linspace(0.5, 0.5, 25)`. Although I do not understand what you are trying to achieve by varying kappa and tau, but if I take it that for those given parameters, you are interested in looking for the roots, here's how I would do it.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Take it as it is
kappa   = 0.1
tau     = 90

def equation(x, parameters):
    kappa,tau = parameters
    return -x + kappa * np.sin(-tau*x)

# Initial guess of x = -0.1
SolutionStack   = []
x0              = -kappa
y               = fsolve(equation, x0, [kappa, tau])
SolutionStack.append(y[0])

y               = fsolve(equation, SolutionStack[-1], [kappa, tau])
SolutionStack.append(y[0])
deltaY = SolutionStack[-1] - SolutionStack[0]

# Define tolerance
tol = 5e-4
while ((SolutionStack[-1] <= kappa) and (deltaY <= tol)):
    y = fsolve(equation, SolutionStack[-1], [kappa, tau])
    SolutionStack.append(y[0])
    deltaY = SolutionStack[-1] - SolutionStack[-2]
    # Obviously a little guesswork is involved here, as it pertains to 0.07
    if deltaY <= tol:
        SolutionStack[-1] = SolutionStack[-1] + 0.07

# Obtaining the roots
Roots = []
Roots.append(SolutionStack[0])
for i in range(len(SolutionStack)-1):
    if (SolutionStack[i+1] - SolutionStack[i]) <= tol:
        continue
    else:
        Roots.append(SolutionStack[i+1]
```

Probably not the smartest way to do it (assuming I even understood you correctly), but perhaps you have an idea now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the code, now it works.

I think you understood it correctly. I want to find all roots for different setups of kappa and tau. I want to automatize this without checking me if all answers are wrong or right, (Think of a huge parameter scan for tau and kappa)

Hope this clarifies my problem.

I dont understand the part where you give fsolve his last output as initial guess. With that deltaY is always zero.

Comment: Ok so the idea was that, (taking this parameters as an example), is that I know my first root, from the left is gonna be at least -0.1 and with that I get the first root, now well I know if I use the solution that I found as an initial guess, it's obvious I will get that same solution back, so I then compare if the difference between the two is zero (meaning they are identical), and if it is, I just move 0.7 to the right and start the next guess. fsolve will return the closes root in the vicinity of the initial guess.

Comment: Every method i tried with fsolve was very unreliable. I now ended up writing my own newton method for the problem. This was very easy and it seems to be very robust.
Still, thank you for your help!